# How can I format R codes in a 'normal' sentence in LaTeX in the language of R?

Tags: r, latex

I'm new to latex and trying to put my R codes in latex, which I have done in the following way:

```
\lstset{language=R,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
    otherkeywords={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    morekeywords={TRUE,FALSE},
    deletekeywords={data,frame,length,as,character},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
}
```

To add a block of code I use `start\lstset` and `end\lstset`.
But to give an explanation of the codes in a sentence, I want to include some text written in R language. For example in the following sentence, I want `sapply` `dflapop` `function(x)` to appear in R language also in color. How can I do this?

The function `sapply` calls the dataframe of the corresponding dataset, which is `dflapop` in this case, and returns a vector conditioned by `function(x)` that sums up all values that are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you tied to actually using LaTeX? If not and you desire to have your code formatted, I would suggest [RMarkdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-1.html) which allows you to write R code and display output as well as write plain text, markdown formatting, and LaTeX style typesetting/equations.